# stop a watch once I change the url

Tags: vue.js

I would like to know how can I change this

```
computed: {
    currentUrl () {
      return this.$route.path
    },
  },
  watch: {
    currentUrl (newURl, firstUrl) {
      if ((!this.$cookiz.get('firstUrl')) && ((this.check === undefined) || (this.check === 0))) {
        this.showPopUp()
      }
    }
  },
```

with a watch that stops once after detect the first change or the url. 
Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a watcher inside `watch`, create it inside the `created` hook and then remove it by calling itself:

```js
created() {
  this.unwatchCurrentUrl = this.$watch('currentUrl', (newURl, firstUrl) => {
    const condition1 = !this.$cookiz.get('firstUrl')
    const condition2 = this.check === undefined
    const condition3 = this.check === 0
    if (condition1 && (condition2 || condition3)) {
      this.showPopUp()

      // Remove watcher
      this.unwatchCurrentUrl()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: But one question, I added a console log before the 3 consts.
The idea of this kind of watch functions is that once execute never be used again, but if I change the url the console log appears on my console every time. Is it correct?

Comment: @MiguelFernándezLizarbe add `console.log('test')` inside the `if` statement. Is it ever get called? If not, it means that the condition in the `if` statement never equal to `true`, so functions `this.showPopUp()` and `this.unwatchCurrentUrl()` never called. Make sure the condition is equal to `true`

Comment: great, now it works perfect, thank you so much